# MySQL Trigger not entirely working

Tags: mysql, triggers, location, signals, message

my trigger is coming back with no errors. But when i test it, no error message is returned and the test data is stored in the table.. Which isn't what I want.

Basically (this is for coursework), I want a trigger that displays an error message when a location other than ***Barcelona*** is inserted into the table.

This is my trigger. As I said, no errors come back, but it doesn't work?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_location_insert_finance
AFTER INSERT ON Finance
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN  
DECLARE LocationTrigger varchar(255);  
DECLARE msg varchar(255);  

SELECT Location INTO LocationTrigger  
FROM Finance  
WHERE Location != "Barcelona";  

IF(LocationTrigger != "Barcelona") THEN  
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'  
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not a valid location';  
END IF;

END$$
```

Comment: modify this: `WHERE Location <> 'Barcelona';` and `IF(LocationTrigger <> 'Barcelona')`

Comment: @Harshil: I wouldn't expect that change (replacing the **`!=`** operator with **`<>`** ) would change the behavior. In MySQL, those two operators are synonyms, both represent the same operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression in the `IF` won't evaluate to TRUE if `LocationTrigger` is null.

And LocationTrigger will be NULL if there are not rows in `Boss` that satisfy the condition in the `WHERE` clause.

I'm not understanding why there's no check of the value being inserted into the `location` column; or why are we running a query of the `Boss` table, when we're comparing to literal value of `'Barcelona'`.

Seems like we'd want this kind of check in a BEFORE trigger rather than an AFTER trigger.

Are we going to allow NULL values for `location`?

If the only value we allow to be inserted for `location` is `'Barcelona'`, and if we aren't allowing NULL values, then we don't need to mess with any query of the `Boss` table. Just do a comparison...

```
 BEGIN
    IF NOT ( NEW.location <=> 'Barcelona' ) THEN
       SIGNAL ...
    END IF;
 END
```

Maybe the goal of the trigger is to enforce a referential integrity constraint (which we'd normally implement by declaring a FOREIGN KEY constraint, rather than implementing a procedure.)

Assuming that a "valid" location is defined by the domain of `location` values in `Boss` table,

and assuming we aren't going to allow NULL values, then:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE ls_location  VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
   -- check if the value being inserted exists in a lookup table
   SELECT b.location INTO ls_location
     FROM Boss b
    WHERE b.location = NEW.location
    LIMIT 1 
   ;
   -- if we didn't find a match, ls_location will be NULL
   IF ls_location IS NULL THEN 
      SIGNAL ... 
   END IF;
END
```

---

If no matching row is found in `Boss`, then `ls_location` will be NULL.

A "not equals" comparison to NULL is going to evaluate to NULL, not TRUE or FALSE.

Boolean logic is SQL is tri-valued... TRUE, FALSE and NULL

```
 SELECT 0     = 1      AS c0
      , 0    <> 1      AS c1
      , 0     = NULL   AS c2
      , 0    <> NULL   AS c3
      , NULL  = NULL   AS c4
      , NULL <> NULL   AS c5
```

Comment: My trigger is a little confusing (i removed everything referring to the 'boss' table, as everything should relevant to the 'finance' table). Yes, you're right in saying that the goal is to enforce an integrity constraint. My integrity constraint for this database would be that the location HAS to be Barcelona. Therefore, i was going to create a trigger that sends an error message if any the location that has been inserted is anything other than Barcelona. (This database is essentially 8 tables and we have a series of tasks to do with said database. With no table exactly related to one another)

Comment: @GeorgeGilliland: implement a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, and all it needs to do is look at the value of location that's being inserted and compare it to a literal **`IF NOT ( NEW.location <=> 'Barcelona' ) THEN`**  raise the exception.  The `<=>` (spaceship) operator is a null-safe comparison that returns TRUE or FALSE even when the expressions being compared are NULL. It's documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.  `a <=> b` is shorthand equivalent to `a = b OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL)`.